# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: java, jackson

I need to convert json to pojo. I Decided to use jackson and have added jackson-core-2.2.0.jar, jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar and jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar to my project's classpath

I created following `Main` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;

public class Json {
private static String SRC= "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      AwardList awardList = null;
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      try{
          awardList = (AwardList) mapper.readValue(new URL(SRC), AwardList.class);
      }catch (JsonGenerationException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (JsonMappingException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.out.println(awardList);

  }
}
```

And following `AwardList` class:

```
public class AwardList {

    private Flights[] flights;
    private String[] connections;

    private SaverEconomy saverEconomy;
    private StandartEconomy standartEconomy;
    private SaverBusiness saverBusiness;
    private StandartFirst standartFirst;
    private SaverFirst saverFirst;


    public Flights[] getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }

    public void setFlights(Flights[] flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }

    public SaverEconomy getSaverEconomy() {
        return saverEconomy;
    }

    public void setSaverEconomy(SaverEconomy saverEconomy) {
        this.saverEconomy = saverEconomy;
    }

    public StandartEconomy getStandartEconomy() {
        return standartEconomy;
    }

    public void setStandartEconomy(StandartEconomy standartEconomy) {
        this.standartEconomy = standartEconomy;
    }

    public SaverBusiness getSaverBusiness() {
        return saverBusiness;
    }

    public void setSaverBusiness(SaverBusiness saverBusiness) {
        this.saverBusiness = saverBusiness;
    }

    public StandartFirst getStandartFirst() {
        return standartFirst;
    }

    public void setStandartFirst(StandartFirst standartFirst) {
        this.standartFirst = standartFirst;
    }

    public SaverFirst getSaverFirst() {
        return saverFirst;
    }

    public void setSaverFirst(SaverFirst saverFirst) {
        this.saverFirst = saverFirst;
    }

    public String[] getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(String[] connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }
}
```

I want to convert json to pojo and save it in the database. I keep getting following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:457)
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:379)
>   at Json.main(Json.java:72)
> ```

Comment: Why you are using different versions of Jackson jars? You have jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-annotations but all of them has different versions? As a first step I would recommend to use the same release versions. Just for the info version 2.5 was released today.

Comment: Your have another version of jackson jars which are loading before these jars. check the other version and remove those

Comment: Worked for me too by using same versions :

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I was getting the exactly same issue. I was using Maven for dependency management and had added dependency for jackson-databind module only like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and then I resolved it by doing this.. I added its transitive dependencies explicitly with the same jackson.version mentioned for each of them in the pom.xml file, as guided [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#get-it)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but note this jar should then occur in the classpath before the jars with the earlier version of jackson.

Comment: This worked for me..thanks.. i have added above both whith my <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> dependancy

Comment: I am using 2.10 version for all three, I m getting this error. Which version would you suggest to resolve this issue .

Comment: If anyone's getting this error after manually copying the three jackson-\*.jar-s under Tomcat's WEB-INF/lib, make sure you don't have older exploded jars under WEB-INF/classes/com/fasterxml/\*.

Comment: This worked for me with version 'v2.14.2' for 'jackson-databind' and 'jackson-dataformat-yaml' and the two additional dependencies mentioned in the answer.

Comment: In meantime it might be better to add https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-bom#usage instead of all transitive dependencies, and removing the versions from the dependencies themselves.

Comment: This solution worked for me while shifting from 2.15.3 to 2.16.0
Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

I came here with a similar issue on Google App Engine. Here is how I fixed it.

First I ran:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

To find who is using the older version. I then excluded that from the offending dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Next I added the newer version of the dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this help others who stumble here.

Comment: If you're using gradle, it should something like this.
  implementation ("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
    }

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. There was some incompatibility between the jackson-version 2.6.3 and another dependency (graphaware-framework-embedded).

**I could resolve the issue by simply removing the dependency on jackson** in my own pom and just let the other dependency load whatever jackson-version it needed.

Answer (score 3):

As of now latest redisson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Latest Jackson jackson.version property is `2.11.2` for me

```
    <!-- faster JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Updating Eclipse references, without this runner configs were accessing earlier edition of jackson project.

```
eclipse:eclipse -U
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue just now while upgrading my project from spring 3 to 4.1.6.

A little background for reference, just in case if it helps anyone running into same issue===> 
       First, it prompted me with error for mappingJacksonconverter vs mappingJackson2converter since the former doesn't exist anymore with spring 4. Once I changed those references in code, I ran into issue with my dispatcher servlet since it had xsd definitions from spring 3 support. Once that's corrected, my last step in journey was this error which you all faced as well.

My solution:
  I had older versions of following jars:
   jackson-annotations,
   jackson-core,
   jackson-databind,
   jackson-core-asl,
   jackson-mapper-asl

I upgraded first 3 jars to 2.10.0.pr1 release and last 2 to 1.9.13 release.

I also had one more older jar i.e.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar which I had to remove as well. Anyways, as error suggested this was the key reason for the mismatch (Like Tobias said in comment prior to mine)

I think only last paragraph is important from this particular question point of view, but I am hoping my narration of issues faced leading up to that may help someone saving 4-5 hrs :) Cheers, folks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I updated the version to a recently released version i.e. 2.12.4 and it worked fine.

Note: I was using another project inside the build path of a larger project in eclipse. The jackson update was done inside the pom.xml file of the smaller project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I upgraded from Jackson `2.11.4` to version `2.12.4`, the mapping error was fixed.