# ObjectMapper java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson

I am trying to map a Json string to a Java Object using ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CustomerData customerData = mapper.readValue(customerDataString, customerData.class);
```

But when I do, I get this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:530)
```

I looked online and checked for the incompatible dependencies in the pom.xml, and it appears to be the right version. So what am I missing?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I guess you have conflicting jackson-versions. You could check mvn  dependency:tree and see if there are other conflicting jackson libs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746750/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-co)

Answer (score 20):

Following **dependencies** must be tally with each other. (Same Version)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you do not have an older version of artifactId "jackson-core" (< 2.3.0) as a dependency.
You can try to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

as first dependency in your pom.