# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: json, rest, maven, tomcat, jackson

I have project which locally works fine but when I deploy war to server and try to execute Rest method, I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.&lt;init>(ObjectMapper.java:474)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.&lt;init>(ObjectMapper.java:393)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(JsonMapperConfigurator.java:44)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.locateMapper(ProviderBase.java:866)
```

I know that it is related with overlapping jars but could not find a solution. When I use [JHades](http://jhades.github.io/), I get messages related with Json or Jackson:

```
file:/C:/Users/justas/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.20.0/google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar overlaps with 
file:/C:/Users/justas/.m2/repository/ppp/ppp/1.0/ppp-1.0.jar - total overlapping classes: 5 - same classloader ! This is an ERROR!

file:/C:/Users/justas/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.4/jackson-core-2.5.4.jar overlaps with 
file:/C:/Users/justas/.m2/repository/ppp/ppp/1.0/ppp-1.0.jar - total overlapping classes: 79 - same classloader ! This is an ERROR!
```

Pom.xml fragment related with Json or Jackson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.</version>
</dependency>
```

I was trying to remove or replace jars but it does not work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried suggested solutions at [exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-co](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746750/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-co)

Comment: Yes. My pom.xml does not contain com.fasterxml.jackson.core explicitly.

Comment: Upvote for JHades. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added and worked like a charm:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```