# Getting NoSuchMethod Error while calling a PostMapping with Json Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-web

I'm creating a webservice, but when I call the http://localhost:8080/mdn/add endpoint, I'm getting a stacktrace, even though I expected that the JSON data would be stored in my database.

**This is the entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abctable")
public class AbcEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "mndt")
    private String mndt;

    @Column(name ="cdate")
    private Date cdate;

    @Column(name= "cno")
    private String cno;

    @Column(name = "customer")
    private String customer;

    @Column(name ="Customer_Name")
    private String customer_name;
}
```

---

**This is the controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ={"/mdn"})

public class MdnBController {

    @Autowired
    MdnBRepository mdnbrepos;


    @PostMapping(value = "/add",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public AbcEntity addDetails(@RequestBody AbcEntity mdnentity)
    {

        return mdnbrepos.save(mdnentity);

    }
```

All other related classes are also present. This is the JSON input I'm trying to send as a request body:

```
{
        "mndt": "300",
        "cdate": "20190114",
        "cno": "999999",
        "customer": "00002005",
        "customer_name": "cus2"
}
```

However, when I execute this request, I get the following stacktrace:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8TypeModifier.modifyType(Jdk8TypeModifier.java:20) ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:413) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:354) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:325) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:161) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]

2019-05-10 18:09:40.761 ERROR 15768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8TypeModifier.modifyType(Jdk8TypeModifier.java:20) ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:413) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:314) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:212) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:126) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:902) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:399) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:303) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.findTypeParameters(TypeFactory.java:279) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._mapType(TypeFactory.java:947) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:386) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:358) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.constructType(MapperConfig.java:268) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1117) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._findExplicitUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1089) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.hasSerializerFor(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:392) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canSerialize(ObjectMapper.java:2410) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canWrite(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:176) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.canWrite(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getProducibleMediaTypes(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:229) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: try removing @PostMapping(value = "/add",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) and keep only value part i.e. @PostMapping(value = "/add")

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing any error or possibly you may want to put the output you are getting ?

Comment: You did not include the actual error, but that normally indicates that you're mixing incompatible versions of libraries.

Comment: Make sure you have selected the correct method name on postman.

Comment: Hi guys, here is the Error

2019-05-10 18:09:40.761 ERROR 15768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8TypeModifier.modifyType(Jdk8TypeModifier.java:20) ~[jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:413) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
 at

Comment: Hi Updated the brief error details above

Comment: Add your `pom.xml` file here. And see [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409798/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-javatype-isreference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mixed versions of Jackson dependencies on your classpath. Looking at your stack trace we see both `jackson-databind-2.5.3` and `jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar`. [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE depends on jackson-databind-2.9.7](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.pom) so use this version and remove 2.5.3.

Comment: That worked, but now after hitting endpoint, abcentity has null properties. need help?

Comment: Please ask a different question, this is a completely different problem. Kindly please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Ok i am asking, please help on that.