# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

Tags: java, spring

Am integrating Ivy with my project and added all dependencies in the ivy.xml file but still getting the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746750/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-co

Comment: I have already added that